# GCE permission denied (publickey)

Tags: authentication, ssh, cloud, connect, google-compute-engine

When I create a new instance in GCE I'm able to ssh to that new instance without an issue.  gcutil checks to see if I have the keys (google_compute_engine) and if not, it will create them for me.  It will then push the keys to the instance and will pause for five minutes to ensure the keys are placed there.  Again, this all works smoothly on a new instance that I create.  This also tells me that my ssh works.

However, when trying to connect to another instance that already exists using "gcutil --project= ssh ", it produces "Permission Denied (publickey).  I removed the keys and re-ran the command and same error.  The expected result would be like above - i.e create keys and push them to the instance.  But this doesn't happen.

ssh -vvv has no useful info.  /var/log/auth.log doesn't even show an attempted connection.

Anyone in GCE world/ssh have any idea why gcutil works so smoothly for one instance but not for the other?  What should I check for debugging this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be something specific to your configuration. Please email gc-team@google.com with the above information. Also: please mention if both instances are in the same project, and include the full gcutil command you're running to connect.

Comment: have you tried use just ssh instead of gcutil? I usually do "ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine <ip addr of the other instance>"

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [the answer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729694/permission-denied-publickey-gssapi-keyex-gssapi-with-mic/16754380#16754380) question that explains how gcutil works.  It covers a number of different scenarios at the end.