# I cant' ssh to GCE vm using key pair generated by myself

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I used command line below to generate a key pair.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/bitnami -C bitnami
```

And I copy the content of bitnami.pub to Metadata SSH Keys.

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDIo5My5G5XLjvjs61mRzndTkfSivLch8udMKAzBP53PFmz0z8/puLxD9NEMKvJe7dSN6bgOqSmhdOQS0Tr8CanCasd4cv9DBRzx9p+Nx5/WxQem6JLYXaQKS/MIQH4zEDLqEYhCpSUOLxM6lnSq/5kRh2/uY6ESvCUUBjNkh9OALIeTjajgIMQidcpfSJi/nxmQkLlybP9yMRHTWfpLEZmGQIUHYBvMBTb9TME31P/t6256awLRL5v1e6D9jR0OouofVNMdPxOYCkmSOcoLrjFX7fbIAVXv6Z5NLilWGG2u/UiqqKpVjQOz0jBoZNtHJWlgZGJRoUOUwOXKyQZQFLN bitnami
```

But when I use ssh like below, I can't ssh to the instance.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/bitnami bitnami@35.237.126.116
```

The error info is like:

```
bitnami@35.237.126.116: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you have a user named `bitnami` that exists on this instance? Did you reboot the instance after copying the keys to metadata? The metadata is read / processed during startup.

Comment: Take a look and follow the instruction from E. Anderson: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729694/permission-denied-publickey-gssapi-keyex-gssapi-with-mic?answertab=votes#tab-top I think is a interesting comment has helped more than ones.

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@John Hanley, you are right. I tried to add a user named bitnami, and that's OK. Many thanks.